# How do I know which ram timings are correct?

Tags: memory, bios, memory-timings

I bought [this RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148347) for one of my systems. The BIOS (latest version for this mobo) has automatically set the timings for 9-9-9-24 1T. This passes memtest86+ fine (10 passes overnight.
[image: CPU-Z Memory Tab]

Earlier versions of the BIOS had the ram set at 9-9-9-27 2T and that also passes memtest86+.

How can I tell which timings are correct? The DIMMs don't have any timing information on the stickers and the packaging does not either. The newegg page doesn't have timings either. I do not understand how to tell which timings are the stock timings for this RAM. 
[image]

If anybody could tell me what the proper timings for this RAM I would appreciate it. If you need any more information I will provide it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

9-9-9-24-1t looks correct to me... perhaps the previous versions of the BIOS didn't support the 9-9-9-24 1t configuration... so it ran the sticks slower.  According to the [manufactures site](http://www.crucial.com/store/partspecs.aspx?IMODULE=CT51264BA1339)... they're rated for CL9... so going faster than that is probably a bad idea (lower-number = faster)

Comment: +1 Thank you for breathing some sanity into this Question by linking and quoting the Manufacturer's website and specs.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the timings presented in the **SPD** are right for your **RAM** on the predefined frequency. Those *settings* are stock and should provide you with stable error-free operation. Small confusion could arise when you are operating on alternative frequencies that get no mention in the **SPD**. There should not be a problem, if it falls behind the max. range that you can see in the **Timings Table**. Furthermore, the combination of timings and freq. that you see there is usually a relaxed set - your **RAM** can probably push out more and with tighter timings. That's what various stress tests are for.

Now, in your particular case, the difference is only in **tRAS** and **Command Rate**. Usually, **tRAS** does not really influence stability as much as the **Command Rate** does, far from it. So, the only thing you'd need to worry would probably be setting the **RAM** into **1T** or **2T**. All in all, if your BIOS has already automatically detected that **1T** can be ran on that frequency - you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The SPD tab shows a lookup table of settings based upon different frequency settings. This is a table which is stored on the stick of ram by the manufacturer. So the correct setting should be the one in the column with the clock frequency you have the RAM set to in the BIOS.

If your frequency is not on the list, consider manually setting the values to ones from a column with next faster frequency (and higher latency).